# Building the logic behind what type of ___ are you quiz in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic, logic

I have a create a "What type of ___ are you?" type of quiz for by blog but not any specific one. I need to build a logic that would work on many quizzes which I can add directly from my admin panel.

Each question will have only 2 options: yes or no.

1. The most basic approach: If we have 'n' questions and 2 options each, it would have a total of (2)^n combinations and asking user to enter answer for each one of them won't be possible. So I put this one aside.
2. Points: We assign 1 point to each question for 'yes' and 0 to 'no'. We also assign a number to each of our possible answers list. At the end, whichever answer's number matches the total, we print it. But this leaves out a lot of combinations and will not be efficient.
3. Instead of numbers, we assign intervals to our answers. Like this: (answer1,0-3), (answer2,3-6). It would work better than 2nd but again, missing out many combinations.

What approach do these website quizzes use? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are just algorithms that you will use, any web frameworks nowadays can suit your need.

For frontend, you can consider React/Angular/Vue

For backend, you can consider Express with Node/Deno in javascript, or Java Spring-Boot, or Python Flask/Django

Any combination of the above will work for your use case.

Comment: I am be using Next JS. I was just confused with what approach I should tackle the situation to get the best out of it.

Comment: Then I would suggest to build a admin dashboard using MERN, and serve the page using Next.js with all the logic and algorithm included in client side, as all the communication you need with the server is adding/removing of the questions, thus saving the server computing power.

Comment: I found a good general approach that would work on multiple personality quizzes. Basically, we first make a list of all possible final results. Then while adding questions and options via admin, we ask a result for each option of every question. At the end of the quiz, we just count which result has maximum number of clicks and display that.